# Getting a json from collection to view in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I am new to backbone.js and is having some problem with my app. I  have a collection which relies on a json data source. I am able to console.log the json in my parse method. Is that enough to bind the collection to my view? I don't understand the use of fetch method.

My collection looks like as follows,

```
(function (collections,model) {
collections.Directory = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        initialize : function(){
            console.log('we are here');
            },
        model:model.item,
        url:'collections/json/data.json',
        parse:function(response){
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            }
    });
})(app.collections,app.models);
```

And my master view looks like this,

```
(function(views,collections){

views.masterView = Backbone.View.extend({
         el : $("#contacts"),
        initialize : function(){
            console.log('view initialize inside render');
            this.render();
            this.$el.find("#filter").append(this.createSelect());
            this.on("change:filterType", this.filterByType, this);
            this.collection.on("reset", this.render, this);
            this.collection.on("add", this.renderContact, this);
            //console.log('we are here'+app.collections.CollectionItems.fetch());
            console.log('view initialize');
        },

        render : function(){

            this.$el.find("article").remove();
            _.each(this.collection.models,function(item){

                this.renderContact(item);
               },this);

            },
             renderContact: function (item) {
            views.contactView = new app.views.ContactView({
                model: item
            });
            this.$el.append(contactView.render().el);
        },
            getTypes : function () {
            return _.uniq(this.collection.pluck("Qno"));
        },
    createSelect : function () {

        var select = $("<select/>", {
                    html: "<option value='all'>All</option>"
                });
    _.each(this.getTypes(), function (item) {
        var option = $("<option/>", {
            value: item.toLowerCase(),
            text: item.toLowerCase()
        }).appendTo(select);
    });
    return select;
    },
     events: {
            "change #filter select": "setFilter",
            "click #add": "addContact",
            "click #showForm": "showForm"
        },
    setFilter : function(e){
        this.filterType = e.currentTarget.value;
        this.trigger("change:filterType");

    },
    filterByType: function () {
    if (this.filterType === "all") {
        this.collection.reset(contacts);
        routerURL.navigate("filter/all");
    } else {
        this.collection.reset(contacts, { silent: true });
        var filterType = this.filterType,
            filtered = _.filter(this.collection.models, function (item) {
            return item.get("type").toLowerCase() === filterType;
        });
        this.collection.reset(filtered);
        routerURL.navigate("filter/"+filterType);
    }
},
    addContact : function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var contModel = {};
        $("#addContact").children("input").each(function(i, el){
            if($(el).val() !== "")
                contModel[el.id] = $(el).val();

        });
        contacts.push(contModel);
        if (_.indexOf(this.getTypes(), contModel.type) === -1) {
                this.collection.add(new Contact(contModel));
                this.$el.find("#filter").find("select").remove().end().append(this.createSelect());
            } else {
                this.collection.add(new Contact(contModel));
            }
    },
    showForm : function(){
        this.$el.find("#addContact").slideToggle();   
    }

        });
      })(app.views,app.collections);
```

my model is very simple and looks like this,

```
(function ( models ) {
    models.Item = Backbone.Model.extend({
        defaults :{Qno:'1',Desc:'hello'}
        });
})( app.models );
```

ihave one js file instantiatin viewsand collections

```
    (function () {

        window.app = {};
        app.collections = {};
        app.models = {};
        app.views = {};
        app.mixins = {};

       $(function(){
                app.collections.CollectionItems = new app.collections.Directory();
                //app.collections.CollectionItems.fetch();
                //console.log(app.collections.CollectionItems.fetch());

                app.collections.CollectionItems.fetch({
                    success: function (collection,response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    }
                });
                //console.log(app.collections.CollectionItems.toJSON());
                console.log('coll started');
                app.views.app = new app.views.masterView({collection: app.collections.CollectionItems});
                console.log('view is jus about fine!!');
                //app.views.pagination = new app.views.PaginatedView({collection:app.collections.paginatedItems});
        });






    var ContactsRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "filter/:type": "urlFilter"
    },
    urlFilter: function (type) {
        master.filterType = type;
        master.trigger("change:filterType");
    }
});

    var routerURL = new ContactsRouter();

    Backbone.history.start();
})();
```

my landing page looks like this with a template in it

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Backbone.js Web App</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/screen.css" />
    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="contacts">

</div>

        <script id="contactTemplate" type="text/template">

            <h1><%= Qno %></h1>

        </script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/underscore-min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/backbone-min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <script src="collections/Directory.js"></script>
        <script src="models/item.js"></script>
        <script src="views/masterView.js"></script>
         <script src="views/simpleView.js"></script>
        <!--<script src="js/backbone.paginator.js"></script>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

I just can't get my head around this. The view is not rendered with the collection data. Please help!

Comment: It looks like haven't posted all your code, so it may help if you can do that. There are a lot of missing/undefined variables in the code you posted. And are you using any templating, that will probably be useful as you seem to be building a lot of DOM elements inside your templates, and templating will clean that up/make it easier to understand.

Comment: my json looks like this                                                                   [{"Qno":0,"Desc":"Desc of Qn0"},{"Qno":1,"Desc":"Desc of Qn1"},{"Qno":2,"Desc":"Desc of Qn2"},{"Qno":3,"Desc":"Desc of Qn3"},{"Qno":4,"Desc":"Desc of Qn4"}]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because the fetch method on your collection is executed asynchronously and has therefore not completed when you create your view (if you look at the console I would expect the log statement in the success callback to display after the log statements underneath). This means that your view render method is called before the collection is populated and the reset event (which you're binding to in your view) is never triggered.

Try updating the code which instantiates everything as follows:

```
   $(function(){
            app.collections.CollectionItems = new app.collections.Directory();
            //app.collections.CollectionItems.fetch();
            //console.log(app.collections.CollectionItems.fetch());

            app.collections.CollectionItems.fetch({
                success: function (collection,response) {
                    console.log(response);
                    app.views.app = new app.views.masterView({collection: app.collections.CollectionItems});
                }
            });
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for responding to my query. Now I have changed the view to be instantiated after the collection is populated. But, the render function is not behaving as expected. I doubt there's something wrong with the collection-model pairing but can't figure out what it is. I am getting nothing when looping through the collection.

Comment: The json that is returned looks like this                                 [{"Qno":0,"Desc":"Desc of Qn0"},{"Qno":1,"Desc":"Desc of Qn1"},{"Qno":2,"Desc":"Desc of Qn2"},{"Qno":3,"Desc":"Desc of Qn3"},{"Qno":4,"Desc":"Desc of Qn4"}]

Comment: [
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn0"
Qno: 0
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn1"
Qno: 1
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn2"
Qno: 2
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn3"
Qno: 3
__proto__: Object
, 
Object
Desc: "Desc of Qn4"
Qno: 4
__proto__: Object
]                                                                     console is logged like this from the fetch method

Comment: In what way is the render function not working as expected? You can rule out a problem with your model collection pairing by inspecting it in your view. Either stick a breakpoint in the render method and make sure your collection is populated or log the values of each item in your each loop - console.log('Model: ', item.get('Qno'));

Comment: When I try to loop through the models in the collection and log somethin, I am getting nothin. But the collection is populated and gets logged inside the fetch method.

Comment: I meant render function is not behavin as expected since I am unable to loop through the models of the collection. It behaves as if the collection has no models even though the collection is populated before instantiatin the view(I am able to log my collection data before instantiatin the view as suggested by you)

Comment: app.collections.CollectionItems.fetch({
    success: function (collection,response) {
     console.log(response);
     
     console.log(app.collections.CollectionItems.length);
     app.views.app = new app.views.masterView({collection: app.collections.CollectionItems});
    }
   })                                           After fetching the response, the collection length is still 0. Am i missing something here?

Comment: From what you've said, it does sound like your collection is not being populated when you call fetch. Are you sure the JSON you're getting back isn't wrapped in another object? Try sticking a breakpoint in your parse method and inspecting the contents of the response parameter. Also, are there any errors appearing in the console? Otherwise I'm at a bit of a loss. One thing you might consider is putting a simplified version in a jsfiddle.net. You might find that in doing so you discover the problem, and if not it will make it easier for someone here to help.

Comment: i don't get what you mean by wrapped in another object. I am getting an array of json objects. Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/bala4kp/PvSNV/2/ . Thanks for the response

Comment: Can you provide a link to the service that returns your JSON?

Comment: Am not using any service. I am using a local '.json' file which has the following content,                                      [{"Qno":0,"Desc":"Desc of Qn0"},{"Qno":1,"Desc":"Desc of Qn1"},{"Qno":2,"Desc":"Desc of Qn2"},{"Qno":3,"Desc":"Desc of Qn3"},{"Qno":4,"Desc":"Desc of Qn4"}]                                     Thanks

Comment: im having the same issue but instead of collection. I'm having the issue in my Model.